# How to shift background color of each row one by one and remove color form previous one in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, animation

Here, is the table ,I want the background color of first row  blue and after 10 sec I want the color of second row to blue and remove the color from the first row. Similarly the third row color change after 10 second to blue and remove from the second row. As much as I add rows in the table the animation be apply to all dynamically. This table data is coming from API so the rows add automatically in the table so I want the animation apply on all the row dynamically...Thanks in advance   [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzraP.png)

```js
var __data = [];

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON('myfile.json', function (data) {

        var getData = '';

        $.each(data, function (key, value) {

            //     var obj=[key,value];
            // console.log(obj);
            __data.push(value);
            getData += '<tr class="my-row" onclick="viewValues(' + key + ')">' + '<td class="para-name" >' + value.name + '</td>' +

                        '<td class="para-value">' + value.value + '</td>' +

                        '<td class="para-unit">' + value.unit + '</td>'
                        +
                        '</tr>';
        });

        $("#scroll").append(getData);

    })


});

function viewValues(ob) {

    console.log(__data[ob].value);
    setInterval(function () {

        document.getElementById('parameter').innerHTML = __data[ob].name;
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = __data[ob].value;
        document.getElementById('unit').innerHTML = __data[ob].unit;
    }, 2000)
}

function color() {
    viewValues(key)
}
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body onload="color()">

    <div class="card">
        <span id="value">25 </span><span id="unit">ppm</span>
        <p id="parameter">Sodium Oxide</p>
    </div>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Parameter</th>
                    <th scope="col">Value</th>
                    <th scope="col">Unit</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="scroll">



            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is `key` in `color`? What have you tried so far? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) _"Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the timer for 3 seconds, you can change it to 10 seconds

```
myTimer = setTimeout(changeBackground, 3000)
```

```js
var myTimer;
var rowCount = $('.table tbody tr').length;
current=0;
     
changeBackground();
function changeBackground()
{  
   $('.table tbody tr').each(function (idx) {
       $(this).removeClass('tr');
       if(current == idx)
          $(this).addClass('tr')
    });
    current=current+1;
    if(current > rowCount - 1)
       current = 0;
    myTimer = setTimeout(changeBackground, 3000)
}
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.tr
{
    background : blue;
    color:white;
    transition:background .3s;
}
.table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
.table td
{
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
        <span id="value">25 </span><span id="unit">ppm</span>
        <p id="parameter">Sodium Oxide</p>
    </div>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Parameter</th>
                    <th scope="col">Value</th>
                    <th scope="col">Unit</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="scroll">
                  <tr>
                    <td scope="col">Parameter 1</td>
                    <td scope="col">Value 1</td>
                    <td scope="col">Unit 1</td>
                </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td scope="col">Parameter 2</td>
                    <td scope="col">Value 2</td>
                    <td scope="col">Unit 2</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td scope="col">Parameter 3</td>
                    <td scope="col">Value 3</td>
                    <td scope="col">Unit 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done mainly through CSS - using JS just to set up the animation and after that it's not necessary to invoke JS.

```js
    var __data = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
/*
    $.getJSON('myfile.json', function (data) {

        var getData = '';

        $.each(data, function (key, value) {

            //     var obj=[key,value];
            // console.log(obj);
            __data.push(value);
            getData += '<tr class="my-row" onclick="viewValues(' + key + ')">' + '<td class="para-name" >' + value.name + '</td>' +

                        '<td class="para-value">' + value.value + '</td>' +

                        '<td class="para-unit">' + value.unit + '</td>'
                        +
                        '</tr>';
        });

        $("#scroll").append(getData);

    })


});

function viewValues(ob) {

    console.log(__data[ob].value);
    setInterval(function () {

        document.getElementById('parameter').innerHTML = __data[ob].name;
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = __data[ob].value;
        document.getElementById('unit').innerHTML = __data[ob].unit;
    }, 2000)
}

function color() {
    viewValues(key)
}
*/
// once you have the table loaded go through calculating the parameters for running the animations

  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('table.table tbody tr');
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    //calculate the delay for each row.i);
    rows[i].style.animationDuration = 3*rows.length + 's';
    rows[i].style.animationDelay = 3*i + 's';
    rows[i].style.animationName = 'highlight';
    }
    document.getElementById('animation').innerHTML = `
@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    background-color: cyan;
  }
  ` + 100/rows.length + '%' + ` {
    background-color: cyan;
  }` + (100/rows.length + 0.1) + '%' + ` {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}`;
});
```

```css
 <style>

body {
    text-align: center;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
tbody tr {
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
}
</style>
<style id="animation">
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div class="card">
        <span id="value">25 </span><span id="unit">ppm</span>
        <p id="parameter">Sodium Oxide</p>
    </div>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Parameter</th>
                    <th scope="col">Value</th>
                    <th scope="col">Unit</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="scroll">
<tr><td>row 1</td><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>row 2</td><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>row 3</td><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>


            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```